# Jquery AJAX submits the form even if confirm() method is false

Tags: javascript, ajax, confirm

```
<div class="report" data-id="55"></div>

<script>
$('.report').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    confirm("do you really want to report this post?");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'forumreport.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'id='+id,
        success: function(){
            alert("reported!!");
        },
    });
})
</script>
```

I want to stop `$.ajax()` method if user clicks cancel on confirm form. However ajax is still sending the id to .php page. What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`confirm` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) returns a boolean indicating whether the prompt is confirmed, therefore you can simply save the resulting boolean in a variable and check whether it is true before executing the AJAX request.

```
$('.report').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var confirmed = confirm("do you really want to report this post?");

    if (confirmed) {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'forumreport.php',
          type: 'GET',
          data: 'id='+id,
          success: function(){
              alert("reported!!");
          },
      });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Confirm` function returns a boolean value indicating whether OK or Cancel was selected (`true` means OK)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Check for result which is returned by `confirm` function:

```
<script>
$('.report').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    if(confirm("do you really want to report this post?")){
       $.ajax({
           url: 'forumreport.php',
           type: 'GET',
           data: 'id='+id,
           success: function(){
            alert("reported!!");
           },
       });
    };

})
</script>
```